# no implicit conversion between string and int in razor view javascript area

Tags: razor

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var destinationId = @(Model.DestinationId == 0?"":Model.DestinationId);
</script>
```

I want to output "" if Model.DestinationId is 0 else display Model.DestinationId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your C# code is trying to return a `string` when the `if` condition yields `true` and returns an `int`(value of `DestinationId`) when the condition expression returns `false`. The compiler is telling you that it is not valid! You need to return the same type from both the cases.

To fix the issue, return the same type from both the cases. You can use `ToString()` method on the `int` type property so that your ternary expression will always return the same type (`string`)

```
var destinationId = @(Model.DestinationId == 0 ? "" : Model.DestinationId.ToString());
```

Although the above will fix your compiler error, it might not be giving what you are after. The above code will render something like this when your `DestinationId` property value is 0.

```
var destinationId = ;
```

Which is going to give you a script error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

and when `DestinationId` property has a non zero value, for example, 10.

```
var destinationId = 10;
```

There are multiple ways to solve the issue. One simple approach is to replace the empty string with something JavaScript understands. Here in the below sample, I am rendering `null` as the value

```
var destinationId = @(Model.DestinationId == 0 ? "null" : Model.DestinationId.ToString());
if (destinationId===null) {
    console.log('value does not exist');
}
else {
    console.log('value is '+ destinationId);
}
```

Another option is to simply read the DestinationId property value and check for 0 in your JavaScript code as needed.

Another option is to wrap your entire C# expression in single or double quotes. But then again you number value will be represented as a string :(, which is not good.

I suggest you to use the correct type(even in JavaScript)